# BaggagedField update value not working in SpringBootTest after migrating from Spring boot 2.7.x to 3.2.3

Tags: spring-boot-3, micrometer-tracing

I have Tracing library which by default propagate the CorrelationId and x-correlation-id into headers of the requests.

That also provides a utility class which is used to set the custom correlationId which can be traced wherever the requests is passed.

The configuration and all other is **working fine with actual application** but when I am trying to run it with SpringBootTest the BaggagedField is not getting updated. Code is as below.

Configuration:

```
package com.test.tracing.configuration;

import brave.baggage.BaggageField;
import brave.baggage.BaggagePropagationConfig;
import brave.baggage.BaggagePropagationCustomizer;
import brave.propagation.Propagation;
import com.test.tracing.configuration.EnsureCorrelationIdPropagationFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;


@Configuration
public class CorrelationAutoConfiguration1 {

    public static final BaggageField CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD = BaggageField.create("correlationId");

    @Bean
    BaggagePropagationCustomizer baggagePropagationCustomizer() {
        return fb -> fb.add(BaggagePropagationConfig.SingleBaggageField
            .newBuilder(CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD)
            .addKeyName("X-MC-Correlation-Id")
            .addKeyName("Correlation-Id")
            .build());
    }

    @Bean
    static BeanPostProcessor ensureCorrelationIdPropagationFactory() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(@NonNull Object bean, String beanName) {
                if (bean instanceof Propagation.Factory) {
                    return new EnsureCorrelationIdPropagationFactory((Propagation.Factory) bean);
                } else {
                    return bean;
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Propagation Factory:

```
package com.test.tracing.configuration;

import brave.propagation.Propagation;
import brave.propagation.TraceContext;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.UUID;

import static com.test.tracing.configuration.CorrelationAutoConfiguration.CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD;

public class EnsureCorrelationIdPropagationFactory extends Propagation.Factory {

    private Propagation.Factory delegate;

    EnsureCorrelationIdPropagationFactory(Propagation.Factory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsJoin() {
        return delegate.supportsJoin();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requires128BitTraceId() {
        return delegate.requires128BitTraceId();
    }

    @Override
    public <K> Propagation<K> create(Propagation.KeyFactory<K> keyFactory) {
        return delegate.create(keyFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public Propagation<String> get() {
        return delegate.get();
    }

    @Override
    public TraceContext decorate(TraceContext context) {
        TraceContext decoratedContext = delegate.decorate(context);
        String correlationId = CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD.getValue(decoratedContext);
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(correlationId)) {
            CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD.updateValue(decoratedContext, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        return decoratedContext;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <aspectjrt-version>1.9.9.1</aspectjrt-version>
        <brave-propagation-aws-version>0.23.4</brave-propagation-aws-version>
        <brave-version>5.14.0</brave-version>
        <zipkin-version>2.23.18</zipkin-version>
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjrt-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-context-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-http</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-rpc</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.aws</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-propagation-aws</artifactId>
            <version>${brave-propagation-aws-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.zipkin2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>${zipkin-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The Utility:

```
public class Correlator {

    private Correlator() {
    }


    @Nullable
    public static String getCorrelationId() {
        return CorrelationAutoConfiguration.CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD.getValue();
    }

    
    public static void setCorrelationId(String correlationId) {
        CorrelationAutoConfiguration.CORRELATION_ID_BAGGAGE_FIELD.updateValue(correlationId);
    }
}
```

TestCase:

```
import com.test.tracing.configuration.CorrelationAutoConfiguration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import io.micrometer.tracing.ScopedSpan;
import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest(classes = CorrelationAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class CorrelatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    private ScopedSpan span;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.span = this.tracer.startScopedSpan("my-scoped-span");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        this.span.end();
    }

    @Test
    public void correlationId() {
        String correlationId = "test-5";
        Correlator.setCorrelationId(correlationId);
        assertEquals(correlationId, Correlator.getCorrelationId());
    }

}
```